# Google trusted store checkout customization

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-1, date

I am using the code below to get the delivery date for trusted store badge

```
 <span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date"><?php echo $deliveryDate=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days")); ?></span>
```

I need to replace the static number 7 with this code

```
 <?php 
    $order_items = $order->getAllItems();
    $maxDelivery = 0;
    foreach($order_items as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        if ($product->getAttributeText('estdelivery') > $maxDelivery) { 
            $maxDelivery = $product->getAttributeText('estdelivery');
        }

    }
    echo $maxDelivery;
?>
```

what would the merged code be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I reckon you can just do:

```
 <?php 
    $order_items = $order->getAllItems();
    $maxDelivery = 0;
    foreach($order_items as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        if ($product->getAttributeText('estdelivery') > $maxDelivery) { 
            $maxDelivery = $product->getAttributeText('estdelivery');
        }

    }
?>

 <span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date"><?php echo $deliveryDate=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $maxDelivery . " days")); ?></span>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly and that would help alot of magento owners who are trying to setup their google trusted store badge, i tried a couple extensions and all failed. The first bit of coding would be great for someone whoo does need a per items delivery date, in our case some of our items take longer than others to arrive and are shipped seperately, thanks saved me from banging my head on the desk about it magento is a finicky one :)

Comment: now we are running into a issue somehow we need to be able to do a adjustment for states like hawaii alaska puerto rico to have a higher delivery date as well as foreign countries due to time going through customs